# Bounding the number of divisors of $2(m^3 - m)$ that are less than $m/4$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assume that $m$ is a positive integer. Find an upper bound on the number of divisors of $2(m-1)m(m+1)$ that are less than $m/4$? This question cropped up naturally on a problem I am trying to solve. But I can't think of how to approach it!

Comment: Um how about $m/4$?

Comment: Thanks! Can I do better?